# Post JSON data along with id in Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to post JSON data along with 2 ids through a Jquery AJAX post. But I am not able to do it.

Following is my code:

```
try {
    var surveyID= localStorage.getItem("surveyId");
    var userDetails = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("userdetails"));
    var providerKey = userDetails["ProviderUserKey"];
    var dataValue = { "str": StringJson};
    var url = APP_URL+"EditSurvey?";
    var param = "SurveyId="+surveyID+"&JSONData="+JSON.stringify(dataValue)+"&UserId="+providerKey;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: url,
           data: param,
           async:true,
        success: function (data) {

            alert('sucess');


            //}

        },  
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Err : " + err.error);
        },

    });
} catch (error) {
     alert(error);
}
```

I get the following error when I debug this in Safari:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and in simulator I get the following error:

[image]

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this? I have to 3 parameters for post

- surveyID
- JSON data
- userID

**Edited:**

The webservice is now changed and all 3 params- i.e. 2 ids and one whole json data is passed to the webservice. Still jquery ajax post is not working. See my code below:

```
 var surveyID= localStorage.getItem("surveyId");
    var userDetails = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("userdetails"));
    var providerKey = userDetails["ProviderUserKey"];
    var dataValue = {"surveyID":surveyID, "userID":providerKey, "str": StringJson};
    alert(dataValue);
    var url = APP_URL+"EditSurvey";
    var param = dataValue;
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           contentType: "application/json",
           url: url,
           data: dataValue,
           success: function (data) {

           alert('sucess');


           //}

           },
           error: function (err) {
           alert("Err : " + err.text);
           },

           });
```

**edited to include stringJson:**

```
var StringJson = JSON.stringify(MainJSON);
 alert(StringJson);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the final json which is being passed is in the exact format as expected by the server.

Try giving:

contentType: 'application/json', 
Accept: 'application/json'

See if it helps.

Comment: on server only one field is accepting json, other 2 are ids

Comment: I think you are trying to construct the url with the ids and the json data combined. Please check the url in POSTMAN extension of chrome if it works with the URL and the exact param data you have given in the ajax call. If it works there, then jump into code and try to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 formData = {
        // all your parameters here
        param1: param1,
        JSONData: formToJSON(),
        UserId: providerKey
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            //success handling
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Err : " + err.error);
        }
    });

function formToJSON() {
    return JSON.stringify({
        dataValue: dataValue
    });
}
```

Comment: actually the webservice is now changed. It expects only one parameter. 2 ids and json --3 of these are now passed as json to the webservice. But this is still not working. See my edited question to see how i pass the params now

Comment: what is value for StringJson?

Comment: see my edited quesiton again. I have included it now with screenshot